# Matching LED Brightness Using PWM

Tags: optics, visible-light, light-emitting-diodes

I am currently working on a project that involves the use of LEDs. For this project, I have to match the brightness of an LED (receiving constant current) using another LED with PWM (the LEDs are white). I thought I had come up with a method that would work. In the end, though, it appeared as if the duty cycle I had calculated was about $2\text{%}$ off.

The first thing I did was build a circuit with an LED connected in series with a $330\Omega$ resistor. I measured the voltage across and current through the LED and calculated the power, which turned out to be $0.018 W$. Then, I built another circuit with an LED connected in series with a $10k\Omega$ resistor. I measured voltage and current again and got $0.00064 W$ as the power. My goal was to match the brightness of the LED with the $330\Omega$ resistor to the LED with the $10k\Omega$ resistor using PWM.

According to the Talbot-Plateau Law, the brightness of a flickering LED is equal to its average brightness. So, I took $0.00064 W$ and divided it by $0.18 W$ to get $0.036$, or $3.6\text{%}$. This is the duty cycle I used to flicker the LED connected to the $330\Omega$ resistor. Comparing the two LEDs, they have a similar brightness, but the PWM one has a brightness that is slightly higher. I tried changing the duty cycle and $1.5\text{%}$ seemed to match it perfectly. I was wondering if there is any specific reason why my calculation is off and any way I can adjust the calculation to make it more accurate. The multimeter I am currently testing with is not necessarily the best or most accurate, but I do not think that using a different multimeter will significantly change anything. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

(I am also open to other methods of matching the brightness)

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: 1.5% instead of 3.6% doesn't look like 2% off: more like 50% off.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite the matching exercise!

You have two different LEDs, and you have not specified what part number they are, so we don't know anything about them.  However, it seems *very* reasonable that the efficiency of the LED varies by 2%.  You did all of your arithmetic based on power consumption, not light output, so if one LED is more efficient than the other, you would see a difference.

It's also possible that the physics of the efficiency of an LED is not constant at different currents.  White LEDs often have phosphors which could have non-linear effects.

Comment: Thank you for the response! That makes sense. I was wondering if I could perhaps take a picture of the two lights and analyze the intensities of the light in the two images. My only concern is having a still image taken of PWM. Would the PWM affect the picture?

Comment: @DTS PWM should generally not affect the picture.  If you use a cellphone, its *possible* that it could adjust the exposure differently (cellphones do a lot of magic to make pictures look good with crappy hardware).  However, if you have a camera that you can lock the exposure settings on, and you can take a reasonably slow picture (compared to your PWM period), you could compare the pictures.  Also, they make light measuring devices to do exactly the kind of measurements you need, with high precision.  Consider using one of them.